# Is this a counter example for a comparison test for sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I’ve recently started learning about sequences and convergence and divergence, and I came across the comparison test for sequences. What I have  is that:

[image]

What if $a_n$ is defined as a periodic function, such as $a_n = 1 + sin (x)$

If $b_n$ is any function that is greater than $a_n$ that does converge, shouldn't $a_n$ converge?

As an example, let $b_n = (3x+2)/(x+1)$

This seems to satisfy the conditions, yet $a_n$ (the sinusoidal function) does not appear convergent...

[image]

Comment: You've mixed up sequences with series.

Comment: That result with blue background is false. Where did you get that?

Comment: @mickep I got it from my textbook (Mathematics for the international student - Mathematics HL (option): Calculus). However, I found similar results after a quick google search, such as in http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx

Comment: But that is, as @CarlHeckman writes, for series and not for sequences.

Comment: @CarlHeckman the blue box I included (from my textbook) says sequences. I double checked the chapter and context, and it seems to be discussing sequences. Is this incorrect? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @mickep as I said above, that is what the textbook says. Are you sure it is incorrect? I just want to double check

Comment: The correct result is given by @CarlHeckman in his answer below. The result as written with blue background is wrong.

Comment: Ok then @mickep thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Comparison Test says that, if $0 \le a_n \le b_n$, then

1. If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ also converges.
2. If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ also diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The result you're trying to prove is false. Let $a_n = (-1)^n + 2$, and $b_n = 5$. Clearly $b_n \to 5$, but $a_n$ oscillates between $3$ and $1$ without converging. You've basically mimicked that example, but with some functions (strictly, you should evaluate your functions at each natural number in order to get a true sequence).

There is a related result, an instance of the squeeze theorem, which states that if $0 \leq a_n \leq b_n$ and $b_n \to 0$, then $a_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** As Carl Heckman noticed, you have probably mixed up sequences and series.

For **series** $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$, such that

> $$0\leq a_n\leq b_n,$$

the following holds true:

> If the **series** $\sum a_n$ diverges then the **series** $\sum b_n$ diverges
>
> If the **series** $\sum b_n$ converges then the **series** $\sum a_n$ converges